# Can be websockets used to create a client to client connection?

Tags: html, websocket

I want to make a client to client conection, using the server like a bridge momentarily, and I was seeing websockets but I don't know if that is posible. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't connect two clients using websockets without a server being the intermediary. The connection to the server would need to be alive throughout.

Comment: but ¿is there no way to transform a client into a websocket server?

Comment: Not that I know of. That's why the client is a client and not a server. To what address would you connect your other client to if you were connecting to another client?

Comment: an IP bring from the bridge's server

Answer (score 6):

There are plans for this in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/#peer-to-peer but I don't think any browsers support it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the issue how two peers get to know each others IPs and setting aside any NAT-related issues making direct TCP connections between peers problematic, the WebSockets protocol itself is only asymmetric up to and including the initial WS handshake performed. After that, WS is fully symmetric.